# help configuring rspamd to be used from remote postfix

Tags: 18.04, postfix, remote, mail

Good day!
my postfix is in different host from my dovecot and rspamd, and everytime a mail comes the postfix will deliver it to my dovecot. Now I am having a hard time configuring my postfix to use the remote rspamd.

I have searched and found nothing.
Setting these:

```
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:11332
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:11332
milter_protocol = 6
milter_mail_macros =  i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
milter_default_action = accept
```

to

```
smtpd_milters = inet:<ip where my rspamd is>:11332
non_smtpd_milters = inet:<ip where my rspamd is>:11332
milter_protocol = 6
milter_mail_macros =  i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
milter_default_action = accept
```

doesn't work
Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if using verion 1.7.4 , chances are rspamd will only allow connections from localhost (see https://rspamd.com/doc/quickstart.html ). You will want to:

- edit `/etc/rspamd/local.d/worker-normal.inc` to meet your configuration:

> bind_socket = "*:11332"

- add firewall rule to protect this port since it will listen to all interfaces including public ones